# Preposition of "We have known each other for a while"

Tags: phrase

How would you say "we have known each other for a while"? Is it:

> Wir kennen uns schon seit einer Weile.

Can other prepositions work instead of "seit"? Also, what other phrases can be used instead of "einer Weile"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it is the best way to say it. You might also find it entirely without preposition

> Wir kennen uns nun schon eine Weile.

which is correct too. You could use "einander" instead of "uns" to sound more high brow and you could replace "eine Weile" by "eine Zeit lang". I think this is mostly a regional thing though. Other alternative is

> Wir kennen einander jetzt geraume Zeit.

And that's pretty much it, I think.